# What happens inside the processor when time.sleep is invoked in a thread?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, language-agnostic

Why do we use time.sleep  in multi-threaded programs and what happens in the CPU, when this instruction is executed

Answer (score 2):

time.sleep is a python (or other application language) construct, not a CPU instruction.  Typically, sleep-like system calls are used to tell the scheduler that you do not wish to execute until the provided epoch arrives (period elapses or absolute time passes).  The scheduler will do your bidding by making the calling thread ineligible for execution until that epoch; in the mean time, it may run other threads or idle itself if there is nothing left to do.

When the epoch arrives, it is typically delivered via an interrupt, which gives the scheduler a chance to make the thread eligible to run again.  If the scheduler deems it appropriate, the thread may start to execute immediately; otherwise it will have to wait its turn.